# Detect if selected element is an anchor on right click

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, right-click

I'm writing a small firefox addon to grab urls and send them to a site. What I want to do is be able to right click on a link (but not have to actually highlight it) and be able to click send and the links href value is grabbed and sent. The bit I'm having trouble with is detecting if the selected element is an anchor and grabbing it's href. Many thanks for any help given :)

Answer (score 1):

nvm, found the solution at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/Extensions#Determining_what_element_was_context_clicked